# Find direction in which the function decreases as quickly as possible

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y,z) = x^2 - 2y^2 + 3z^2$

If you are standing at the point $(1,1,1)$ and want to stay on the plane $2x + y -z = 2$, in which direction should you travel in order to decrease the value of f as quickly as possible?

I understand that this question has something to do with finding the vector that gives the directional derivative its greatest negative value. However, I am confused on how to solve it based on being on the plane given. Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try getting one variable in terms of the other two with the plane equation. For example, you could have $z=2x+y-2$. Then substitute that in for $z$ in the main equation, and you will only have two variables.

Comment: The direction of maximum slope is the gradient. If you want to remain on the plane you have to project the gradient on the plane (but this is a hasty idea, I have not checked the computations)

Comment: This is an optimization problem with a constraint. Use a method that deals with that (namely KKT or Lagrange's multipliers).